# how to export app object in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I init my app object in app.js:

```
var app = express();
var reg = require('./routes/reg');
app.use('/reg',reg);
... ...
module.exports = app;
```

and I call app.get() in reg.js:

```
var app = require("../app.js");
... ...
app.get("jwtTokenSecret");
```

my files are like this in the project:

```
 ---app.js

 ---routes

    ---reg.js
```

but I found that app is {} in reg.js and the app.get() is not a function, so how to solve it? thanks a lot

Comment: did you export an object in app.js?

Comment: You have circular dependecies: `app.js` depends on `routes/reg.js`, and `routes/reg.js` depends on `app.js`.

Comment: yeah, module.exports = app

Comment: did you require('express')?

Comment: yes, I  had require it

Comment: One route would be to have reg.js export a function that takes the app as a parameter and then pass the app from app.js to your reg.js require statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request` object:

```
// inside reg.js:
console.log( req.app );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but why I can't get app by doing like that?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with stodb-- "use `request` object". This also works with routes:

app.js

```
// app.js
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.test = 'abc';
module.exports = app;
```

user.js

```
// ./api/routes/user.js
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.app.test);
});
// abc
```